# Pathfinding - Directions and Spaces moved

Tags: c#, coordinates

I have only started with C# (I am as green as it gets) and am working on a maze solution with a grid system of x and y coordinates. I can find the open points through the maze and I have a stack of points which is returned from the pathfinder.

public Stack Path { get; }

**However I want to print this out into human readable directions. IE travel 4 spaces left and 2 down type of thing.**

Stack of points for example:

X Y Format

```
6,60
7,60
8,60
9,60
10,60
10,61
10,62
10,63
10,64
10,65
11,65
```

Now going through this, in human readable that would mean to travel 5 Spaces Down, 5 Spaces Left and 1 Space down.

5 Spaces Down (6,60 | 7,60 | 8,60 | 9,60 | 10,60)

5 Spaces Left (10,61 | 10,62 | 10,63 | 10,64 | 10,65)

1 Space Down (11,65)

However how do I iterate through the stack to find the change of directions and how many spaces to go in that direction? I assume check how long either the x or y is constant and for how many.... but I have no idea how to do this! Please help a noob :(

**Also is it possible to write out how many times the walking direction changed?**

Comment: What did you try? Did you create a Grid class with position properties or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to determine that (6,60) -> (7,60) = Down, and how to store the 'current direction' and increment a 'distance travelled', then all you need to do is figure out what to do if the direction between the next two points is different to your current direction.

(BTW if you want extra points, you can do it fairly readily using `points.Aggegrate( )`, where your accumulator is responsible for building up the list of directions from each new point. But I wouldn't suggest this unless you're comfortable with functional programming concepts)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to simply keep track of the current direction and the number of steps we take in that direction, and anytime the direction changes, output the number of steps we took and reset our counter and direction.

First, a quick enum to track direction:

```
enum Direction
{
    None, Up, Down, Left, Right
}
```

Then, a method that takes in a list of points and echoes the directions to the user. I used comments in the code instead of describing it here.

One thing to note is that, according to your example, an increases in the first number (`X`) indicates a movement down, and an increase in the second number (`Y`) indicates a movement Left.

The code also assumes that only either `X` or `Y` will change between points. To allow both to change, you'd need to then track both horizontal and vertical movement changes.

Note that you'll need to add `using System.Drawing;` to the top of your file to reference the `Point` class:

```
private static void ProcessPoints(List<Point> points)
{
    if (points == null || points.Count < 2) return;

    // Setup current direction and step count
    var direction = Direction.None;
    var steps = 0;

    // Process each point, starting with the second one
    for (var i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        // Get the previous and current points
        var previousPoint = points[i - 1];
        var thisPoint = points[i];

        // If we haven't moved, continue
        if (previousPoint == thisPoint) continue;

        // Calculate the current direction
        var currentDirection = thisPoint.X == previousPoint.X
            ? thisPoint.Y == previousPoint.Y
                ? Direction.None
                : thisPoint.Y > previousPoint.Y ? Direction.Left : Direction.Right
            : thisPoint.X > previousPoint.X ? Direction.Down : Direction.Up;

        // If this is our first step, set the direction
        if (direction == Direction.None) direction = currentDirection;

        // If our current direction is the same as the last one, increment steps
        if (currentDirection == direction)
        {
            steps++;
        }
        // If we've changed direction, output how many steps we took in
        // the previous direction and reset our steps and direction
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Walk {steps} spaces {direction}");
            steps = 1;
            direction = currentDirection;
        }
    }

    // Output the last leg of our journey
    Console.WriteLine($"Walk {steps} spaces {direction}");
}
```

To test it with your sample data, we can just create a list of those points and pass it to our method:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var points = new List<Point>
    {
        new Point(6, 60),
        new Point(7, 60),
        new Point(8, 60),
        new Point(9, 60),
        new Point(10, 60),
        new Point(10, 61),
        new Point(10, 62),
        new Point(10, 63),
        new Point(10, 64),
        new Point(10, 65),
        new Point(11, 65),
    };

    ProcessPoints(points);

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

Note that my result is slightly different than yours, because I start with `0` steps and no direction. The first point is just that - the point you're standing on when you start, not a point you've stepped to from somewhere else, so the initial leg is only 4 steps, not 5:

[image]

Comment: Wow that’s amazing.... that’s more help than I was expecting from someone. Thank you, that’s perfect!